# How do continuationists respond to Justin Peters' challenge to modern charismatic prophets?

Tags: prophecy, spiritual-gifts, cessationism, doubt, continuationism

#### Who is Justin Peters

From https://justinpeters.org/:

> Justin Peters Ministries is a worldwide expository preaching and teaching ministry. We focus on teaching the sufficiency of God's word and exposing the false teachings of the prosperity, health and wealth gospel. Justin preaches a gospel deeply rooted in the sufficiency of scripture.

> Justin Peters is an evangelist committed not only to the inerrancy of God’s Word but also its sufficiency. The ministry exists to evangelize the lost and equip believers with the tools needed to deepen their understanding of scripture and their love for Christ. In all things Soli Deo Gloria (Romans 11:36).

About [Justin Peters' YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/c/justpreach/about) (155K subscribers):

> My YouTube channel exists to glorify God through the teaching and preaching of His word. When our knowledge of God is deepened, our love for God is deepened (Philippians 1:9). It is my desire to both "teach sound doctrine and refute those who contradict" per Titus 1:9. Though none of us does it perfectly, I strive to speak the truth and to speak it in love (Ephesians 4:15).

#### The Challenge

On April 20, 2022, Justin Peters Ministries uploaded a video titled *My Open Challenge To the Charismatic Prophets: Here's Your Big Chance To Prove Me Wrong!* ([link](https://youtu.be/kGxCoLUC6kI)).

This [website](https://protestia.com/2022/04/21/justin-peters-issues-open-challenge-to-charismatic-prophets-heres-your-chance-to-embarrass-me/) quotes Justin Peters' challenge in written form:

> > “**I want to give you a chance, not only to redeem yourself, but also to embarrass me**. All of you know I’ve been, I’ve been pretty hard on you, rightly so I think, pointing out…your complete and total prophetic faceplant over the last two years, like over and over and over and over and over and over.
> >
> > So, here’s your chance to redeem yourself and to prove me wrong. Embarrass me. Okay? **Embarrass this old fuddy-duddy of a cessasionist**. All right, here’s my challenge. The war is raging in Ukraine. I want any one of you between now -I’m recording this on the evening of April the 20th 2022-… and May 1, that gives you about 10 days. That’s plenty of time to either shoot up to heaven, or just start engaging God in a conversation I want you to ask him, **“how’s the war in Ukraine going to end?”**
> >
> > I want you sometime between now and May 1 put up a video timestamp so it can be verified and all that good stuff. I want to see it. You tag me on it. Hey, if you take me up on this challenge, word will get around and I’ll know about it, believe me, I’ll know about it.
> >
> > **So you put up your video and you tell me, you tell all of us, when is the war going to end and how is it going to end?** Who’s going to win this war? Is it going to be Russia or is it going to be Ukraine? Or is there going to be some kind of a settled peace maybe where Russia gets the Donbas region and Ukraine maintains its sovereignty? How’s this thing going to end? Okay, be specific. How is it going to end and when is it going to end?”
>
> Peters then goes on to offer them generous terms. They don’t even have
> to give him a specific date, but can give him a two-week timeframe “ie
> second half of October, the first half of August.”
>
> Calling out several prophets by name, from Kris Vallaton to Troy Black
> to Kat Kerr, he notes that they claim to be in constant regular,
> face-to-face contact with God and many like Kerr claim to be
> constantly visiting heaven to get their daily download. Kerr claimed
> just the other day that God has told her what color of outfits she
> needs to start wearing, and some have even said that God tells them
> what kind of toothpaste to use, so even one of them must have some
> insight into this major global event, right? Surely one of them might
> have heard something about it in their daily discourses with the Lord,
> right? Right?
>
> The gauntlet has been thrown down, with Petes the Elijah figure to
> these 450 prophets of Baal.
>
> Let’s see what they come up with.

#### Question

How do continuationist Christians who believe in the modern continuation of the gift of prophecy and that God continues to call prophets respond to Justin Peters' challenge and overall skepticism toward modern prophets?

---

#### Appendix - Screenshot

[image]

([source](https://protestia.com/2022/04/21/justin-peters-issues-open-challenge-to-charismatic-prophets-heres-your-chance-to-embarrass-me/))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A comparable challenge was issued to Jesus by the scribes & Pharisees:

> 38 Then certain of the scribes and of the Pharisees answered, saying,
> Master, we would see a sign from thee.
>
> 39 But he answered and said unto them, An evil and adulterous
> generation seeketh after a sign; and there shall no sign be given to
> it, but the sign of the prophet Jonas:
>
> 40 For as Jonas was three days and three nights in the whale’s belly;
> so shall the Son of man be three days and three nights in the heart of
> the earth. (Matthew 12:38-40)

To be sure, while I very much believe in the reality of modern prophets and that God is capable of dispensing any gift in the present that He dispensed in the past, I am highly skeptical of religious teachers who claim to use signs/charisma to draw attention to themselves, rather than to Jesus.

Jesus Himself regularly deferred to the Father.

In Jesus' warning against false prophets (see Matt. 7:15-20) there are at least two clear implications:

- There will be false prophets
- There will be true prophets (otherwise the instruction is unnecessary, He could simply warn against all prophets rather than teaching how to discern true vs. false)

In summary, Peters is asking the wrong question. If God gives a promise we can put His promise to the test (e.g. Malachi 3:10, John 7:17), but we do not dictate to God what He will or will not tell us.

While there may indeed be a good case for skepticism towards *some* who claim a prophetic calling, this does not logically justify rejection of *all* who claim to speak in the name of God. Some of the people of Jesus' day used the examples of false Messiahs (such as Judas the Galilean) as grounds for rejecting all purported Messiahs, and in so doing rejected the real Messiah. Emulating the generalizations of those who rejected the Son of God is an inadvisable strategy.

---

<sup>Additionally, I do not believe the type of toothpaste I use is particularly high on God's priority list.</sup>

Comment:  It's possible that God could give some sort of temporal guidance to prompt a person with allergies to switch to a different type of toothpaste. For example, a specific ingredient might be responsible for toothpaste allergies - e.g. fluoride, flavoring agents, gluten, fragrances, and cinnamic aldehyde can all cause allergic reactions.

Comment: Right. "Prophesy this! Who struck you?" displayed a misunderstanding of prophecy, another spiritual blindness of the Sanhedrin. I probably sympathize with Peters' lack of patience for charlatans, but he's acting a bit like one himself with this.

Comment: @Jess, interesting possibility. I am grateful not to suffer from toothpaste allergies, but I'll grant you that God may provide guidance on the matter to those who do.